# How to navigate back programmatically in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

Most of Simulink actions is backed-up with a command-line code that does the same. 
I'm looking for a piece of code that throws me back to the previous block, exactly as the backward arrow.

Any idea?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a bit of dirty hack but seems to work for me and I can't find a built in command to navigate back.

Since the keyboard shortcut for the back button is ALT+LEFT, I wrote this simple function to simulate that keypress.
I use the `hilite_system` to try to grab focus on the simulink window

Filename: **navigateBack.m**

```
function navigateBack
            import java.awt.*;
            import java.awt.event.*;

            rob=Robot;
            hilite_system(gcb)
            % ALT + LEFT :
            rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT)
            rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT)
end
```

If you run `navigateBack` from the matlab command window, it does the same as pressing the back window in simulink.